# is there any function javascript that, if the window window.open (url) is open not open anymore?

Tags: javascript

is there any function javascript that, if the window window.open (url) is open not open anymore?
I want to know if there is that possibility. please.
Example of my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JNLP</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        //Funcao que faz a aplicacao abrir automaticamente.
        function OpenInNewTab(url) {
            var win = window.open(url,'_parent');
            win.focus();
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = OpenInNewTab("jnlp.jsp")>
<p><%=request.getParameter("nome") %><p>    
<b>Ambiente de teste.</b>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-  1.4.3.min.js">   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: some tricks with cookies/localStorage maybe?

Comment: It may be a translation problem, but it's very unclear what you are trying to ask.